# OpenCV: Grab frame from livestreamer every second, without storing video on disk

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming

I'd like write a python script that grabs a frame from `livestreamer` every second, for processing with openCV. All the examples I've found record a video on disk and process it while the video grows and grows, but that will only work for a certain time if storage is limited. These examples use openCV's `VideoCapture`, which can be used to wither read data from a file (filename constructor) or from a camera interface (camera index constructor).

My first idea was to use a pipe that I can write `livestreamer`'s output to, and use the pipe's name as an argument to `VideoCapture`'s constructor. That doesn't seem to be supported, though.

The second idea was to create some kind of virtual camera which the stream can be written to, so that I can use `VideoCapture` on that camera. I just don't know if that is possible, and if/how it would work.

Another possibility that is even more fuzzy (to me) is to write data to a temporary file until openCV can grab a frame, then delete that file, and repeat. Every second I can decide to process the grabbed frame, otherwise discard it. Again, I have no idea how that could work, and how I should manage the file so that it works as intended.

In short: how can I stream from `livestreamer` to openCV without an intermediate file, and discard or grab frames for further processing?